# I need to secure this PHP code from SQL injection attacks

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I need to secure this code from SQL injection attacks, possibly using `mysql_real_escape_string`.  Where and how do I apply it?

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("database");

$sql="INSERT INTO email (address) VALUES ('$_POST[address]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "<center>THANK YOU!</center>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just wrap your post value in mysql_real_escape_string():

```
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[address]);

$sql="INSERT INTO email (address) VALUES ('$address')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is less for teaching and more for authoritative answers to less-common questions.

What you've got is a common question, "how do I use this function," and it's much better to use the PHP docs to answer that sort of thing. So for example, you look up `mysql_real_escape_string` in the documentation and you find this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Which has example code like:

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
?>
```

Adapting this into your case would give:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO email (address) VALUES ('%s')",
               mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']));
```

Or you could do it in two phases,

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'])
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO email (address) VALUES ('$email')"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are we to adapt the authoritative answers to each case of a questioner that doesn't search for and find and apply such answers on their own?

Comment: Oh, "authoritative answers"? "Less common questions"? You are apparently mixed Stackoverflow with some other site. :) Anyway, sprintf looks useless in the last line, while die() in the first one is plainly wrong.